# Want to automate a Windows GUI for testing

Tags: automated-testing, open-source

Please give some ideas or free tools by using i can automate testing a windows GUI.

tasks :  after opening the GUI , login credentials ,going to different windows inside the GUI,giving inputs ,entering something from drop downs and clicks etc

If any free tools are not there , can i use some scripting language to automate e.g python ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyWinAuto in Python: https://pywinauto.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .i hav already python installed in my pc .plz give some time to help me in installing the pywinauto as i am getting some error while installing

Comment: pywinauto 0.6.1 should have installation problems fixed. Feel free to ask any questions on GitHub or on StackOverflow (tag "pywinauto"). I'm monitoring all of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few tools available for automating Windows GUI.

One of the more know once are as follows:

1. Unified Functional Testing(UFT) by HP but this one is a paid one.
2. AutoIT which is a free.

Answer (score 0):

If screenshot-driven app testing is an option for you, there is [Sikuli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikuli).

Sikuli is a visual scripting language for performing automated software testing of Graphical User Interfaces using Screenshot images of the software to be tested.

Comment: Hi , is it possible to automate scrawling of mouse using sikuli??

Comment: Sikuli supports scrolling with the WHEEL function: 

wheel(WHEEL_DOWN, 8)  # Scrolls down 8 times